# Why is my form POSTing some data but not all

Tags: php, html, mysql, post

I have a modal containing a form that i'm trying to use to update the status of a record but it's POSTing the ID data but not the status data and I can't figure out why.

The only thing that is slightly different in my code is I list the contents of the MySQL table out in a table and then you click on a row which opens a modal specific to that row (I make it specific by adding the ID to each modal do it can be identified).

Also for reference i'm using MaterializeCSS

**HTML Form**

```
                <!-- Edit Status -->
                <div id="editStatus<?= $prep['prepId']; ?>" class="modal" style="width:25% !important;">
                  <div class="modal-content">
                    <h4>Update Status</h4>
                    <form action="" method="POST">

                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="input-field col s12 m12 l12">
                          <select name="updateNewStatus" required>
                            <option selected value="<?= $prep['prepStatus']; ?>"><?= $prep['prepStatus']; ?></option>
                            <option value="Awaiting Action">Awaiting Action</option>
                            <option value="Awaiting Parts">Awaiting Parts</option>
                            <option value="Actioned">Actioned</option>
                            <option value="WIP">WIP</option>
                            <option value="Complete">Complete</option>
                          </select>
                          <label>Status<span class="red-text">*</span></label>
                        </div>
                      </div>

                      <input type="hidden" name="updateId" value="<?= $prep['prepId']; ?>">

                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="input-field col s12 m12 l12">
                          <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light blue right" type="submit" name="updateStatus">Update
                            <i class="material-icons right">add</i>
                          </button>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </form>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!-- End Edit Status -->
```

**PHP One Submit Code**

```
if (isset($_POST['updateStatus'])) {
  $vehicleUpdateQuery = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE preparationReport SET prepStatus = ? WHERE prepId = ?")->execute([$_POST['updateNewStatus'], $_POST['updateId']]);
  $vehicleUpdateQuery = null;
}
```

**Code to open modal (for reference)**

```
                    <a href="#editStatus<?= $prep['prepId']; ?>" class="modal-trigger">
                      <div class="chip <?= $chipBackground; ?>"><?= $prep['prepStatus']; ?></div>
                    </a>
```

Comment: My guess is that you are submitting it with the first option selected, while `$prep['prepStatus']` is empty.

Comment: I've tried changing the Status in MySQL as this was my first thought and it still doesn't submit any data. If I have a Status set it will overwrite the Status with nothing so it becomes empty

Comment: Would look more closely at the rendered HTML source and use console tool. Also, `var_dump` the _POST.

Comment: I've done ```var_dump``` the _POST and it's not passing the data